# Upgrading(cross-grading) Red Hat 5 from 32-bit to 64bit

Tags: redhat, 64-bit

Is it possible to upgrade a 32bit instance of RedHat to a 64-bit instance.

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,
you would need to replace everything with it's 64 bit version.

You would have to reinstall.

Comment: Thought as much, but was worth asking here any way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have reinstall everything it will not upgrade !!